# Word Add-in: MAC IndexedDB behavior is strange

Tags: macos, office-js, add-in, cpu-word

I have stored some data from word add-in into IndexedDB. So, For that session, I am able to retrieve data and work with that.

But when I close the word(Completely **Quit** from menu), and reopens, then I open word add-in and I don't get access to data into IndexedDB. Also, not getting any error.

Again, when I close add-in and reopen, I get access to data. So, I don't get access only first time when I completely quit word and reopens again.
It's strange behaviour, any help will be appreciated.